# Get Owner Profile Image Flikr API

Tags: android, flickr

I am using flickr API in my project, everything is working fine but i stuck at point where I am not able to get user's profile picture.

For example i am getting below type response

```
<user nsid="12037949754@N01" url="http://www.flickr.com/people/bees/" />
```

But not getting user image URL , can any one please help me out?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's really very simple to find out the profile picture of any user which is called buddyicons. The API format/syntax is:

> `http://farm{icon-farm}.staticflickr.com/{icon-server}/buddyicons/{nsid}.jpg`

For example: http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8573/buddyicons/116479554@N04.jpg

Here in this example, icon-farm=9, icon-server=8573 and nsid=116479554@N04

By default, the above example will give you default image of size 48*48(Each user has this size image may or may not exist large, medium images), but if you want large, medium, small profile pictures then just append _l, _m, and _s at the end of **nsid** respectively.

For example: http://farm9.staticflickr.com/8573/buddyicons/116479554@N04_l.jpg

Hope this help you and resolve your issue and might be useful to other users also who face the same issue.